# how do i merge average and max pooling in keras

Tags: python, keras, theano

I am trying to merge max pooling layer and average pooling layer for CNN using Keras. Im using Theano backend.

Below is my code:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D
tower_1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_img)
tower_2 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(tower_1)
tower_1 = AveragePooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(tower_1)
tower_1 = keras.layers.average([tower_1,tower_2])
tower_1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(tower_1)
output = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(tower_1)
```

but i got the following error:

```
ValueError: padding must be zero for average_exc_pad
Apply node that caused the error: AveragePoolGrad{ignore_border=True, mode='average_exc_pad', ndim=2}(Elemwise{Composite{(i0 * (i1 + Abs(i1)))}}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceInc;::, ::, :int64:, :int64:}.0, TensorConstant{(2,) of 2}, TensorConstant{(2,) of 2}, TensorConstant{(2,) of 1})
Toposort index: 137
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, 4D), TensorType(float32, 4D), TensorType(int32, vector), TensorType(int32, vector), TensorType(int32, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(32, 32, 64, 64), (32, 32, 33, 33), (2,), (2,), (2,)]
Inputs strides: [(524288, 16384, 256, 4), (139392, 4356, 132, 4), (4,), (4,), (4,)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown', array([2, 2]), array([2, 2]), array([1, 1])]
Outputs clients: [[InplaceDimShuffle{0,2,3,1}(AveragePoolGrad{ignore_border=True, mode='average_exc_pad', ndim=2}.0)]]

Backtrace when the node is created(use Theano flag traceback.limit=N to make it longer):
  File "C:\Users\aiza\Anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 1272, in access_grad_cache
    term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
  File "C:\Users\aiza\Anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 967, in access_term_cache
    output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
  File "C:\Users\aiza\Anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 967, in <listcomp>
    output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
  File "C:\Users\aiza\Anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 1272, in access_grad_cache
    term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
  File "C:\Users\aiza\Anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 967, in access_term_cache
    output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
  File "C:\Users\aiza\Anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 967, in <listcomp>
    output_grads = [access_grad_cache(var) for var in node.outputs]
  File "C:\Users\aiza\Anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 1272, in access_grad_cache
    term = access_term_cache(node)[idx]
  File "C:\Users\aiza\Anaconda3\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\theano\gradient.py", line 1108, in access_term_cache
    new_output_grads)

HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.
```

What is the correct way to merge max and average pooling layers into one pooling layer?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a custom pooling function for yourself. While searching how to do so, I found [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7045) which can be useful for you which states

> Hi. If this is just for your own use, I can suggest the following:
>   Make a copy of the "pooling.py" file in your local python directory,
>   and rename it to something like "custom_pooling.py" . It will have all
>   the needed module imports - check in this [link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/keras/layers): Then, select the
>   pooling class that is closest to what you want to implement and rename
>   it to "class RMS_Pooling1D(Layer):" etc. When you are ready, just
>   import this class like any other layer. I created my own layer in a
>   similar way. I hope this helps. Thanks.

Above block quote is for RMS pooling you can average of `average` and `max` pooling.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to concatenate those 2 layers like this:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, AveragePooling2D, concatenate

tower_1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_img)
tower_2 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(tower_1)
tower_1 = AveragePooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(tower_1)
tower_1 = concatenate([tower_1,tower_2])
tower_1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(tower_1)
output = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(tower_1)
```

to average try:

```
from keras.layers import average

input_img = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))

tower_1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(input_img)
tower_2 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(tower_1)
tower_1 = AveragePooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(tower_1)
tower_1 = average([tower_1,tower_2])
tower_1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu')(tower_1)
output = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='same')(tower_1)
```

Comment: I want to merge the two layers and get the average values example given the result of the maxpooling is ((255,255),(255,255)) and the result of the average pooling is ((128,255),(255,128)), i want the output to be ((190,255),(255,190))

Comment: The error still exist while trying the code you provided.

Answer (score 0):

The error disappeared after removing the padding='same' attribute.